# FileHandle is behaving unexpectedly in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, file-handling

First of all, the file system in a Windows computer is straight forward. Things are stored in "drives" of which the primary is usually `C` drive. Each drive is denoted by a letter. I have figured out the libGdx on desktop easily. It is simple. I find myself confused by the terminology in Android, however. I have had trouble working with the Android file system in general. There seems to be a big mess in the terminology in my head. I have a file manager on my phone. I created the folder `/mnt/sdcard1/myapp` and created a simple text file reading "Hello World!"

I created an internal FileHandle pointing to the file. It didn't read the file and threw an error. I read the documentation and realized my err. I read further and though my best choice was to use the external handle. So I did.

```
FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.external("myapp/mytext.txt");
```

I checked if the handle existed next:

```
public void create()
{
    System.out.println("" + handle.exists());
}
```

The result is `false`. I doubled back and made sure it existed again, and it does. This is somewhat weird. The Local handle is definitely not there (I read the documentation), and the absolute produced the same results as the external handle when I checked for its existence.

Comment: 'I created the folder \mnt\sdcard1\myapp'. Impossible. You mean /mnt/sdcard1/myapp ? Please show the used code.

Comment: 'Gdx.files.external("myapp\mytext.txt");'. Did you try  Gdx.files.external("/mnt/sdcard1/myapp/mytext.txt"); ? Absolute? Use that!

Comment: 'made sure it existed again, and it does.'. Please explain exactly what you did.

Comment: Which Android version in use?

Comment: @greenapps I did not copy and paste the code. It seems I typed the wrong slash in the question. I will edit. As for your suggestion, doesn't external point to `/mnt/sdcard1/`? And `Gdx.files.absolute` require the `/mnt/sdcard1/` to be explicitly declared? 5.0 is the version.